# Conditional Expectation Formula on discrete random Variable Using Indicator Function

Tags: conditional-expectation

Conditioned on a discrete random variable, the conditional expectation is given by the formula :
$$E(X|Y=y)=\sum xp(x|Y=y)$$
However I've found another formula in Wikipedia that given an event H:
$$E(X|H)=\frac{E(X 1_H)}{p(H)}$$
Can anyone provide the derivation from one formula to the other ? (H is the event Y=y)
Thank you for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_x xP(x|Y=y) = \sum_x \cfrac{xP(x, Y=y)}{P(Y=y)} = \cfrac{1}{P(Y=y)}\sum_xxP(x \cap Y=y)$$

$$X1_{Y=y} = \begin{cases} X, &Y=y \\ 0, &\text{else} \end{cases} \\ \therefore P(X1_{Y=y} = x) = P(X=x, Y=y) \therefore \sum_x xP(x \cap Y=y) = \mathsf E[X1_{Y=y}]$$